eBPF: The sequence of 8193 jumps is too complex
I am trying to parse the packet payload in an eBPF program. The packet payload is a collection of attributes, each with a 2-byte header followed by the actual attribute value. First byte in the header contains the attribute id, and the second byte contains the length of the attribute.
My eBPF program tries to find the offset of a particular attribute in the packet. The program's main loop first checks the attribute's id at the current offset; if it matches the required attribute ID, then it breaks out of the loop. Otherwise, it parses the length of the attribute, increments the offset by that length, and repeats the same procedure.
The program is listed below
while (field_offset < MAX_PAYLOAD_OFFSET)
    {
        if (data + field_offset + 2 >= data_end)
        {
            goto EXIT;
        }
        uint16_t* x = (uint16_t*) (data + field_offset);
        char y = (*x & ATT_ID_MASK) >> ATT_ID_SHIFT;
        if (y == args->field_id)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        char len = *x & ATT_LEN_MASK;
        if (len > MAX_VALUE_SIZE)
        {
            goto EXIT;
        }
        
        field_offset += len;
        
    }

The corresponding eBPF bytecode generated is as follows
while (field_offset < MAX_PAYLOAD_OFFSET)
     115:   bf 39 00 00 00 00 00 00 r9 = r3
     116:   57 09 00 00 ff ff 00 00 r9 &= 65535
     117:   25 09 22 00 31 00 00 00 if r9 > 49 goto +34 <LBB1_14>
;         if (data + field_offset + 2 >= data_end)
     118:   bf 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 r8 = r4
     119:   0f 98 00 00 00 00 00 00 r8 += r9
     120:   bf 89 00 00 00 00 00 00 r9 = r8
     121:   07 09 00 00 02 00 00 00 r9 += 2
     122:   3d 59 17 00 00 00 00 00 if r9 >= r5 goto +23 <LBB1_20>
;         if (y == args->field_id)
     123:   69 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 r9 = *(u16 *)(r0 + 0)
;         char y = (*x & ATT_ID_MASK) >> ATT_ID_SHIFT;
     124:   69 82 00 00 00 00 00 00 r2 = *(u16 *)(r8 + 0)
     125:   bf 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 r8 = r2
     126:   77 08 00 00 0c 00 00 00 r8 >>= 12
;         if (y == args->field_id)
     127:   5d 98 0b 00 00 00 00 00 if r8 != r9 goto +11 <LBB1_21>
;         for(;idx<args->action_count && idx < MAX_ACTION_LIST; idx++){
     128:   79 a2 f0 ff 00 00 00 00 r2 = *(u64 *)(r10 - 16)
     129:   0f 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 r2 += r1
     130:   69 24 06 00 00 00 00 00 r4 = *(u16 *)(r2 + 6)
     131:   15 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 if r4 == 0 goto +20 <LBB1_14>
     132:   b7 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 r5 = 0
     133:   07 03 00 00 02 00 00 00 r3 += 2
     134:   0f 71 00 00 00 00 00 00 r1 += r7
     135:   bf 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 r0 = r7
     136:   07 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 r0 += 16
     137:   07 01 00 00 18 01 00 00 r1 += 280
     138:   05 00 2a 00 00 00 00 00 goto +42 <LBB1_9>

0000000000000458 LBB1_21:
;         if (len > MAX_VALUE_SIZE)
     139:   67 02 00 00 38 00 00 00 r2 <<= 56
     140:   bf 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 r8 = r2
     141:   c7 08 00 00 38 00 00 00 r8 s>>= 56
     142:   0f 83 00 00 00 00 00 00 r3 += r8
     143:   c7 02 00 00 20 00 00 00 r2 s>>= 32
     144:   65 02 01 00 00 00 00 04 if r2 s> 67108864 goto +1 <LBB1_20>
     145:   05 00 e1 ff 00 00 00 00 goto -31 <LBB1_4>

This eBPF program fails while loading with the following error
The sequence of 8193 jumps is too complex.
processed 67395 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 17 total_states 733 peak_states 723 mark_read 6

Can someone please help me understand why the verifier thinks that this loop contains 8193 jumps.

maybe the bpf_loop() helper could work for you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107380/are-loops-allowed-in-linuxs-bpf-programs - you'll have to create a "context" that holds the xdp data buffer/size and the current field offset.

What you have here is called a "bounded loop". The way the verifier proofs that this code is safe is by exploring every possible iteration of this loop. So it will start at field_offset = 0, then explore all possibilities.
The while body has 3 conditional ways to exit that loop, and the default go-around for the next round jump. The verifier is single threaded, it can only check 1 flow at a time, so what it does is maintain a list of yet to be checked branches. So if we imagine the verifier goes from field_offset=0 to field_offset=128, then it will have at least 384 unexplored possible ways this program could execute. And this number can compound for conditional jump after the where body as well.
To limit memory use, the verifier will bail if there are to many of these states in this case 8192. So its not that your code contains 8193 jumps, but rather that the jumps cause to many states to keep track of.

I get this error only when I increment the field_offset by a variable value of len, instead of a constant value. I also get this error even when I reduce the bound values to a very low number.

Right, if you increment by a constant value, then the each loop iteration there is only one possible state to consider for the next iteration of that loop. But len could be any value between 0 and MAX_VALUE_SIZE so the verifier has to consider way more possible states.
